# How to read urls accessed in any browser(Firefox, Chrome, IE)

Tags: c#, network-programming, network-traffic

I need to read urls when they are accessed(e.g loaded) in browsers for a logging program using C#, I've looked at FiddlerCore and Pcap.Net but I have not been able to get them to do what I want and they seem very heavy and convoluted for something as seemingly simple as getting basic traffic information from the network.

Hope someone can help.

Comment: Have you had a look at this [network sniffer in c#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17031/A-Network-Sniffer-in-C)?

Comment: I would not call sniffing SSL traffic as "getting basic traffic information from network"...